# Finding the current week and previous week date range in PHP

Tags: php, date

What's the simplest method to do this in PHP?

I need to make variables to be used in SQL queries.

For example, today is 06-MAY-2015.

```
$current_monday = '05-MAY-2014'
$current_friday = '09-MAY-2014'
$last_monday    = '28-APR-2014' 
$last_friday    = '02-MAY-2014'
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: What is the first day of the week according to you?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php - Did you try to solve this yourself?

Comment: Depending on your need you might be better of using WEEK-command in sql. (It works in MySQL but I guess in other databases as well)

Comment: The @bestprogrammerintheworld made it to SO!

Comment: @AbraCadaver - Forgive me I'm slow here. What do you mean? :-)

Comment: We've been waiting for the @bestprogrammerintheworld to arrive for some time.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - Ahhh. Wait no more ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime()` accepts relative formats which makes this easy to do:

```
$current_monday = (new DateTime('Monday this week'))->format('d-M-Y');
$current_friday = (new DateTime('Friday this week'))->format('d-M-Y');
$last_monday    = (new DateTime('Monday last week'))->format('d-M-Y');
$last_friday    = (new DateTime('Friday last week'))->format('d-M-Y');

05-May-2014
09-May-2014
28-Apr-2014
02-May-2014
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gMjbig)

Answer (score 0):

```
$nextMonday = new DateTime('next monday');
$nextFriday = new DateTime('next friday');
$thisMonday = new DateTime('this monday');
$thisFriday = new DateTime('this friday');
$lastMonday = new DateTime('last monday');
$lastFriday = new DateTime('last friday');
```

Now to make this usable in mysql, just add `->format('Ymd')`

... Eg. `$thisMonday->format('Ymd');`

This will return a date in the format of `20140506` which is friendly to DateTime columns in Mysql

Comment: If it is a Monday or Tuesday, won't "next Monday" get you the wrong day? [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8WtKVM)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question was,
but perhaps you can try:

```
$time = time(); //today
$tmr = $time+(24*60*60);

echo date('Y-m-d', $tmr);
```

also:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Answer (score 0):

see also strtotime() http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
strtotime("+1 week");
```